# Anyone knows how to authenticate with GCP without any python libraries?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I only know how to do it with the current supported libraries - but now I need to do some work with google cloud Filestore and there is no library for it yet.

Anyone can help me out how to create a session with Python using service account?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since Filestore API is discovery based you can use [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client). It is [listed](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/) as supported. Alternatively you can use [google-auth](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html). Here is an example to [list instances](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.instances/list):

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    '/path/to/your/service_account_key.json', scopes=scopes)
authed_session = AuthorizedSession(credentials)
response = authed_session.get(
    'https://file.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/[YOUR_PROJECT]/locations/[LOCATION]/instances')
print response.json()
```

Answer (score -1):

You are able to manage data for Cloud Filestore from the [gcloud tools](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/copying-data)
You can authenticate the gcloud tool with a service account as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing)